# How to make Eclipse DLTK hightlight syntax?

Tags: eclipse, tcl, dltk

I have installed "Dynamic Languages Toolkit" (tried versions 2.0 and 4.0) on Eclipse Juno, but although I added "Dynamic Languages Toolkit - TCL Development Tools", the Tcl code does not get syntax highlighted, nor do Shell scripts. I read that even syntax help (proposals for options) is available, but it won't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last time I tried — quite a long time ago — it “just worked”…

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://blogsai.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/configuring-eclipse-as-tcltk-ide/

Its a little out dated but I remember that this worked just when it says use:

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/1.0/

Instead use this:

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/3.0/

But I would advise you to use vim. because vim rules :)

Comment: Whether or not vim is better than eclipse isn't the question here

Answer (score 1):

If you have opened the file before you installed the Dynamic Languages Toolkit (DLTK) then you might have associated your .tcl file with the eclipse default editor which does not do the syntax highlighting.

In the Project Explorer (left hand side) right click on the file you wan to edit and select

**Open With --> Tcl Source Editor**

or if that isn't available

**Open With --> Other...**

and scroll down to "Tcl Source Editor"